# C# Adding/Subtracting String Numbers Together

Tags: c#, string, linq

If I am given the following string of number, is there a way to add/subtract the numbers up together using a LINQ query?

```
string numbers = "1 + 1, 2 - 1, 3 + 3";
```

So I will end up with something like:

`string numbers = "2, 1, 6";`

Comment: first split on comma, then split on operator and then you can use a switch case to perform the operation

Comment: Splitting on commas will always be the first step, as Renuka mentioned. After that, use a library like http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/381509/Math-Parser-NET-Csharp to evaluate the math expressions.  Then glue the strings back together with `String.Join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing your own evaluator you can use [DataTable.Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx) for performing the evaluation. Or you can use [DataTable.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Data;

string numbers = "1 + 1, 2 - 1, 3 + 3";
string[] equations = numbers.Split(',');
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var values =equations.Select(x => dt.Compute(x, null));
var output = string.Join(", ", values);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output - `2,1,6`

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this existed.  Here is the documentation of the expression format for anyone else looking at this answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Data processing part you have to do in method which you can call as part of linq

Example

```
string processNumber(string numbers)
{
   if (numbers.contains("+"))
    {
        var operands = numbers.Split("+");
        return string.Format("{0},",int.Parse(operands[0].Trim()) + int.Parse(operands[1].Trim()));

    }

    if (numbers.contains("-"))
    {
        var operands = numbers.Split("-");
        return string.Format("{0},",int.Parse(operands[0].Trim()) - int.Parse(operands[1].Trim()));

    }

   return string.Empty;
}
```

Now your Linq query should look like this

```
string numbers = "1 + 1, 2 - 1, 3 + 3";

string results = string.Concat(numbers.Split(",").Select(x=> ProcessNumber(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
string numbers = "1 + 1,2 - 1,3 + 3";
string output=String.Join(",", numbers.Split(',').Select(x=> getSum(x)));
```

Where `getSum()` is defined as follows:

```
 public static int getSum(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            int num1, num2;
            string[] param = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (!int.TryParse(param[0], out num1)) { return 0; }
            if (!int.TryParse(param[2], out num2)) { return 0; }
            switch (param[1])
            {
                case "+":
                    return num1 + num2;
                case "-":
                    return num1 - num2;
                case "/":
                    return num1 / num2;
                case "*":
                    return num1 * num2;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**Note :** This will works fine only if all the inputs follows same pattern, Additional spaces or commas will lead to exception. Since we are dealing with indices.

Comment: answer provided by you is correct but 'HereToLearn' probably want to know a readily available Linq which generate an expected result. But as I understand currently we do not have such intelligent Linq which identify operator in string and perform that operation which produces result.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string numbers = "1 + 1, 2 - 1, 3 + 3";
        var newnumber = string.Join(", ",numbers.Split(',')
            .SelectMany(x => x.Trim().Split(' '))
            .Select((x,i) => new {Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index/3, i => i.Value)
            .Select(x => {
                switch(x.ElementAt(1)){
                    case "+": return int.Parse(x.ElementAt(0)) + int.Parse(x.ElementAt(2));
                    case "-": return int.Parse(x.ElementAt(0)) - int.Parse(x.ElementAt(2));
                    case "/": return int.Parse(x.ElementAt(0)) / int.Parse(x.ElementAt(2));
                    case "*": return int.Parse(x.ElementAt(0)) * int.Parse(x.ElementAt(2));
                    default: return 0;
                }
            }));
        Console.WriteLine(newnumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
You can modify according to your requirement.

```
    int sum = 0;
    int sub = 0;
    string numbers = "1 + 1,2 - 1,3 + 3";
    string num="";
    int count = 1;
    string[] words = numbers.Split(',');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
       if(word.Contains("+"))
       {

        string[] addition=word.Split('+');
        foreach(string value in addition)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
        num=num+sum+",";
        sum = 0;
       }
        if(word.Contains("-"))
        {
            string[] subtraction = word.Split('-');
            foreach (string value in subtraction)
            {

            if(count==1)
            {
                sub = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                sub = sub-Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
            }
             num=num+sub+",";
             sub = 0;
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```